# Openshift application build error: "JBAS014807: Management resource '[(\"subsystem\" => \"deployment-scanner\")]' not found"

Tags: java, jboss, openshift

I have had this error for a long time, but it seems OK with running the application. However, I am always concerned that there might be some hidden costs down the road if I don't fix it.

This is a J2EE application with Springframework, MySQL and exposed RESTFul web services.

I tried various places to find an answer, but have been less than successful. Did anyone have similar experience on this same problem in the past?

Thanks for your help

John Zhu

```
2014/04/19 16:21:10,014 ERROR [org.jboss.as.controller.management-operation] 
(management-handler-thread - 4) JBAS014613: Operation ("read-resource") 
failed - address: ([("subsystem" => "deployment-scanner")]) - failure description: 
"JBAS014807: Management resource '[(\"subsystem\" => \"deployment-scanner\")]' 
not found"
```

Comment: Did you find what it means? :)

Comment: I have the same issue. My app is currently not deploying, but if you say you had this before and your app was deployed, then maybe I can ignore this?

Comment: I still have the error msg, but code works OK

Comment: I think it is probably the deployment system trying to figure out if JBoss is deployed, I see this error when I do the git push: "remote: CLIENT_MESSAGE: Could not connect to WildFly management interface, skipping deployment verification", so I suspect the two are related.

Answer (score 0):

This error can safely be ignored. When the WildFly cartridge starts up, it attempts to verify that your app has been deployed successfully. To do this, it first checks if the deployment scanner is running. If it's not running yet, the error message mentioned in this post will occur in the log and the cartridge will wait a bit and attempt to check again if the deployment scanner is running. If the deployment scanner is still not available after a certain amount of time, the deployment verification step gets skipped. The app will still get deployed successfully though, the confirmation just won't appear in the output when creating the instance/issuing a git push.